# how can i do mysql query to find a user everytime he is logged on a table, and all the other users with him, filtered by date, and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am making a covid log db for easy contact tracing.

these are my tables

```
log_tbl (fk_UserID, fk_EstID, log_date, log_time)
est_tbl (EstID, EstName)
user_tbl (User_ID, Name, Address, MobileNumber)
```

I wanted to write a statement that shows when and where an individual (`User_ID`)
enters an Establishment (`EstID`),

```
SELECT l.*
FROM log_tbl l
WHERE (l.EstID, l.log_date) IN (SELECT l2.EstID, l2.log_date
FROM log_tbl l2
WHERE l2.User_ID = 'LIN78JFF5WG'
                            );
```

[[Result of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLTBl.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLTBl.png)
this currently works,
but it still has to be filterd by +-2 hours based on the time the when `User_ID` was logged on `log_tbl`, so that it would narrow down result when first query would spit out 1000 logs. Because these Results will be Contacted, and to reduce Costs, it needs to be narrowed down to less than 50%.

So, table below should not include first 2 and last one because it doesn't fit with 1, the date, and 2 the time, in relation to the searched user`LIN78JFF5WG`
[[Unfiltered Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoQtK.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoQtK.png)

```
   FROM log_tbl
    WHERE User_ID = 'LIN78JFF5WG' 
    AND (BETWEEN subtime(log_tbl.log_time, '02:00:00') AND addtime(log_tbl.log_time, '02:00:00'
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't have any idea how to join the two queries

and result should include
`EstID`, `Name`, `Address`, `MobileNumber`, `log_date`, `log_time`   sorted by Date

Imagine it like this,

There are 3 baskets full of tomatoes,
2 of the baskets have rotten tomatoes inside.

Do you throw away the whole basket full of tomatoes?
No.. you select the rotten tomato, and others close to it, and throw them away.

I need that for the DB, instead of Getting Result for the Whole Day,
I only need the People who are in close contact with The Target user.
is it possible to do this on mysql? I have to use mysql because of reasons..

Here I include the data sample fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=050b2103d3adf5828524f49066c12e74

Comment: The data sample are still the same as the one you posted before?

Comment: That `+-2 hours` need to compare against what? The current time like `NOW()`?

Comment: yes, should i include data sample? 
and no, `+- 2hours` is compared to the time the `UserID` was logged into `log_tbl`

Comment: I've included the sample data fiddle in your question. According to you previous data sample and the query that you're using now, what kind of result/output would you like to get by adding the hour comparison? Please post an illustration of your desired output.

Comment: what else should i add? or is my question too complicated?

Comment: I don't think it's complicated but there are some mismatches in your data sample with the output you're looking for. For example the searched user `LIN78JFF5WG` have more than 1 record in the sample data you've provided but in the expected result you only show 1 record to fetch on the '2021-06-14' date. How about other dates for user `LIN78JFF5WG`? Should it be in the result too?

Comment: yes, theres supposed to be multiple entries for the people. because its an entry log, people can come and go..
lets say `LIN78JFF5WG` is covid positive, and i have to get the people in close contact with him, and he went to Establishment 1 on 3pm , and 3 on 8am on june 12.
there should be 2 "groups" of `LIN78JFF5WG` contaning the +-2 hours in the result .
idk if im being too complicated, but this is the best method i can think of to narrow the search.. maybe you have any idea on how to narrow it down?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234310/discussion-between-twisted-kindness-and-fano-fn).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just friendly tips: If you have follow-up questions, feel free to post them as a new question. You can also link this question if it provides additional context.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL supports window functions with the `range` window frame specification.  I would suggest:

```
select l.*
from (select l.*,
             sum(case when fk_UserID = 'LIN78JFF5WG' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by log_date
                  order by log_time
                  range between interval 2 hour preceding and interval 2 hour following
                 ) as cnt_user
      from log_tbl l
     ) l
where cnt_user > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6695a02694c2eaa4e6f62ae0b3c6069) is a db<>fiddle.

You can then annotate the results would other columns from other tables to get your final result.

This should be *much* faster than alternative methods.

Note, however, that you have a flaw in this logic, because it is not checking four hours between 0:00-2:00 a.m. and 22:00-0:00.  You can store the date/time in a single column to make it easier to get a more accurate list.

Comment: @TwistedKindness . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions not by invalidating answers on existing questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understand your requirements.
but I write sample sql so that we can make it clear

```sql
select *,(select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(log_date," ",log_time)) as ts from log_tbl where fk_UserID='LIN78JFF5WG') as target_time 
    from 
        log_tbl as l 
    -- simple join query.to get intend information
    left join user_tbl as u on (u.User_id=l.fk_UserID)
    left join est_tbl as e on (l.fk_EstID=e.EstID)
    -- mysql datediff only return day as unit.so we convert to timestamp to do the diff
    where  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(l.log_date," ",l.log_time)) - target_time between 60*60*2 and 60*60*2



-- solution two
-- but I suggest you divide it into two sql like this.

select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(log_date," ",log_time)) as ts from log_tbl where fk_UserID='LIN78JFF5WG';
-- we get the user log timestamp.and use it in next query

select *
    from 
        log_tbl as l 
    -- simple join query.to get intend information
    left join user_tbl as u on (u.User_id=l.fk_UserID)
    left join est_tbl as e on (l.fk_EstID=e.EstID)
    -- mysql datediff only return day as unit.so we convert to timestamp to do the diff
    where  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(l.log_date," ",l.log_time)) - [target_time(passed by code)] between 60*60*2 and 60*60*2
```

Comment: i added a scenario on the post, i hope it helps.

Comment: First Solution `#1054 - Unknown column 'target_time' in 'where clause'`

Comment: and about the last line
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[target_time(passed by code)] between 60*60*2 and 60*60*2 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 8`

Comment: ` #1054 - Unknown column 'l.ID' in 'order clause'` after using your sql, i cant access log_tbl anymore.